# Geometric classification models

Tags: machine-learning, classification, mathematics, linear-algebra

In class we have been presented with a **Geometric classification model** such that the goal is to construct a linear decision boundary
$\bf{w} \cdot \bf{x} = t$; where $\bf{w}$ is the vector from the center of the negative class to the center of the positive class (see figure below), and $\bf{x}$ is an instance to be classfied.

For the above model we have: $t = \frac{(\bf{p} - \bf{n}) \cdot (\bf{p} + \bf{n})}{2}$

[image]

Can someone please explain how we get the decision boundary, i.e. t.
Why is it the dot product of the vector $\bf{w}$ and $\bf{n} + \frac{\bf{w}}{2}$. I have been trying to understand this through linear projections, but I am stuck.

Comment: It's the dot product of $w$ and $(p+n)/2$, **not** $n + (w/2)$. Think of it like this: positive samples are projected to $p$, on average, and negative samples to $n$, on average.  The halfway point between them gives the decision boundary.